# Create a link dynamically with in specific tag or in div with specific id/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is below:

```
<div id="ID1">
    <div id="ID2">
        <!-- blah blah -->
    </div>
    <div id="ID3">
        <!-- blah blah -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to generate code with Javascript or jQuery dynamically below first DIV.
Code generated should be like one shown below.

```
<div id="ID1">
    <a href="#" style="float: left;"><img src="imageLink" /></a>
    <div id="ID2">
        <!-- blah blah -->
    </div>
    <div id="ID3">
        <!-- blah blah -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I am new to javascript and jquery so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some methods are given below.
1st:

```
$("ID2").prepend('<p>content here</p>');
```

2nd:

```
$('<p>content here</p>').prependTo("#ID2");
```

3rd:

```
.before()
```

and 4th:

```
.after()
```

Answer (score 2):

With method `prepend()` you can add code before all the children inside your selector.
Try this:

```
$('#ID1').prepend('<a href="#" style="float: left;"><img src="imageLink" /></a>');
```

If you want to add the code when the page is loaded you have to insert the code inside `document.ready` like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ID1').prepend('<a href="#" style="float: left;"><img src="imageLink" /></a>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ID1').prepend($('<a/>',{
    href : '#',
    css: {
      float: 'left'
    },
}).prepend($('<img/>',{
    attr:{
        src:'imageLink'
    }
})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepend()`

```
$("#ID1").prepend('<a href="#" style="float: left;"><img src="imageLink" /></a>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below snippet

```
$(function() {
  $("<a href='#' style='float:left;'>a will be added here<img src='imageLink'></a>").prependTo("#ID1");
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJfQm/5/)